# Intermediate-Advanced Counting Problem

Tags: combinatorics

How many standard 6-sided dice do I have to roll to guarantee that some nonempty subset of them add up to a multiple of 5?

Comment: This sounds like a pigeonhole principle problem. What should the pigeons be? What about the pigeonholes?

Comment: 30 would work as it would guarantee that you have 5 of one number. Probably not optimal though.

Comment: @Mastrel Actually you'd only need 25 to guarantee that. Worst case is four of each of the six, the next one has to make it five of one number. And you'd need less because any time you have a one and a four you have it. So we can limit this further but I don't have details worked out yet.

Comment: A lower upper bound is 20 because 1 and 6 are both 1 mod 5

Comment: And even lower yet to say that a 4 completes a 1 or 6, a 6 or 1 completes a 4, and a 2 completes 3 and 3 completes 2. So 9? We also ignore any 5s.

Comment: It must be greater than 5 because 1,1,1,1.

Comment: @Mastrel it might be equal to 5, so say greater than 4.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz I meant greater than or equal.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we roll $n$ dice such that there is no subset that adds to a multiple of 5. Let the numbers on them be $x_i$. Then none of the $x_i = 5$. Then $x_1+x_2 \not \equiv 0 \mod{ 5}$ so that leaves 5 options for $x_1$ and 4 for $x_2$. Likewise $x_1+x_3, x_2+x_3, x_1+x_2+x_3 \not \equiv 0 \mod{5}$. This removes three options for $x_3$ if $x_1 \not = x_2$ and two if $x_1=x_2$. So $x_3$ will have at most 3 option. Likewise $x_4$ will have at most 2 options. And $x_5$ will have at most 1 option and $x_6$ will have no options. So it must be $n \leq 5$. However the example 1,1,1,1 shows that it must be $n \geq 5$. Hence it must be $n= 5$.

Comment: You mean "Then suppose $x_{1}+x_{2} \not \equiv 0 \text{mod} 5$"

Comment: I guess I was supposing out $n$ dice don't satisfy the hypothesis. I have made the appropriate edits